# Formula for hypo

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Can someone please tell me the chemical formula for just "Hypo"?

This question came up in previous exams and I don't know what is the general /chemical formula for just "Hypo". I can find the formula for hypo chlorite and hypo bromide, but I am unable to find formula for just " Hypo"

Comment: Could it be that "hypo" is actually an abbreviation of something that is entirely unrelated to chemical formulae? For example, I think "hypo" can be used to refer to hypotonic solutions used in clinical rehydration.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto In this case, a hypotonic solution means below tonic solution. In essence, what I said about having one less oxygen in the ion complex.

Comment: @LDC3 As far as I understand, hypotonic rehydration solutions have nothing to do with hypo-oxyanions. Rather, they're just specially prepared aqueous solutions with total osmolarity lower than that of blood (so there is a net addition of water to the body), while containing essential ions which may be dangerously low in dehydrated patients, such as potassium. Providing water with an inadequate electrolyte balance can actually help kill a severely dehydrated person faster.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto You took my comment literally. What I am pointing out is that hypotonic (below tonic, lower salt content) is similar to the ion complexes where the prefix hypo- indicates less oxygen than the ion without the prefix. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the day when photographs were processed chemically rather than digitally, "hypo" was the chemical used to remove unexposed, undeveloped silver chloride, bromide and/or iodide from the emulsion to fix the image.  The chemical was a solution of sodium thiosulfate, $Na_2S_2O_3$.  The common name at the start of photography was sodium hyposulfate...

Comment: Right, sodium hyposulfate, $Na_2S_2O_3$ has one less oxygen than sodium sulfate, $Na_2SO_4$ (although it exchanged the oxygen for a sulfur).

Comment: I agree with @User58220 My teacher had told us to write formulas for some of the common names of compounds like - blue vitriol... and hypo was one of them which is sodium hyposulfate.

Answer (score 1):

First, hypobromide does not exist, hypobromite does.

Hypo- is not a formula per see. It is an indicator that the oxide has one less oxygen than the -ite oxide.

Examples:

> chlorite ==> $ClO_2^-$
>
> hypochlorite ==> $ClO^-$
>
> bromite ==> $BrO_2^-$
>
> hypobromite ==> $BrO^-$

Answer (score 1):

In chemistry, the prefixes *hyper* and *hyper* are often used to denote the number of oxygen atoms in oxoacids as compared to the *normal* oxoacid. The prefixes are taken from Greek.

- hyper ($\upsilon\pi\epsilon\rho$) = **above** in the sense of *more than* or *super*
- hypo ($\upsilon\pi o$) = **below** in the sense of *less than*

Consequently, there is no general formula for these prefixes.

The prefixes are used in medicine too, e.g. to refer to conditions resulting from vitamin levels above (*hypervitaminosis*) or below (*hypovitaminosis*) an average and healthy level.